# GWT Browse files/directories

Tags: gwt

Here is my requirement:

In my application, I want to get a path of file from user and process the file accordingly.

I am providing a text box in which user can directly enter the path.

Or user can opt to choose a file by clicking on Browse button and selecting a file.

Which widget shall I use to browse local files and directories?

I found one widget called FileUpload but whenever I get the fileName by fileUpload.getFileName, it does not give me the whole path.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't need the whole path.

Please see the links below.

The first link covers the client side and the second one the servlet side.

http://gwt.google.com/samples/Showcase/Showcase.html#!CwFileUpload

http://commons.apache.org/fileupload/using.html