# in GWT, How to build a system that allow users to upload their image into a folder in Webserver?

Tags: file, gwt, file-upload, upload

In `Java Desktop` application, we can allow users to upload files into a folder in the WebServer, something like this

```cs
 File rootDir = new File( "/home/bala/temp" ) ;  
      if( FileUpload.isMultipartContent( request ) ) {  
          DiskFileUpload fileUpload = new DiskFileUpload() ;  
          Iterator iterator = fileUpload.parseRequest( request ).iterator() ;  
          while( iterator.hasNext() ) {  
                 FileItem fileItem = ( FileItem ) iterator.next() ;  
                 File file = new File( rootDir , fileItem.getName() ) ;  
                 fileItem.write( file ) ; }  
          } 
     else { throw new Exception( "Invalid request " ) ;  }
```

But How we do this in **Gwt** or **GWTP**? Does **Gwt** contain any class supporting this?

Comment: pls see this answer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8441599/gwt-browse-files-directories/8442764#8442764

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would use [gwtupload](http://code.google.com/p/gwtupload/wiki/GwtUpload_GettingStarted) because of its simplicity.

In Client Side use Multiuploader if you want to upload multiple files:

```java
  public void onModuleLoad() {
    MultiUploader uploader = new MultiUploader();

    RootPanel.get().add(uploader);

    uploader.addOnFinishUploadHandler(new IUploader.OnFinishUploaderHandler() {
      public void onFinish(IUploader uploader) {
        if (uploader.getStatus() == Status.SUCCESS) {
          UploadedInfo info = uploader.getServerInfo();
          System.out.println("File name " + info.name);
          System.out.println("File content-type " + info.ctype);
          System.out.println("File size " + info.size);
        }
      }
    });
  }
```

In server side, just override the `UploadAction` servlet provided with the library.

Edited: Note that the method receives a list of `FileItem`, each FileItem is the temporary information and content of the uploaded file but is not a real java `File`. Here is where you put your business code to create your own `dirs` structure, to process them or even to store them as blob fields in a ddbb. In this case we are getting all the files and storing them in the temp folder (note that this folder is different in linux, windows, etc).

```java
  public class SampleUploadServlet extends UploadAction {
    @Override
    public String executeAction(HttpServletRequest request, List<FileItem> sessionFiles) throws UploadActionException {
      String response = "";
      for (FileItem item : sessionFiles) {
        if ( ! item.isFormField()) {
          try {
            File file = File.createTempFile("upload-", ".bin");
            item.write(file);

            /// Send a customized message to the client.
            response +=  file.getAbsolutePath() + "\n";
          } catch (Exception e) {
            throw new UploadActionException(e);
          }
        }
      }

      /// Remove files from session because we have a copy of them
      removeSessionFileItems(request);

      /// Send your customized message to the client.
      return response;
    }
  }
```

If your servlet already handles multipart requests, you can use the standard way in GWT uisng `FileUpload` and `FormPanel`, although you will miss progress bars, file-chooser styling, etc.

```java
  // Add a form-panel to your document
  final FormPanel form = new FormPanel();
  form.setEncoding(FormPanel.ENCODING_MULTIPART);
  form.setMethod(FormPanel.METHOD_POST);
  form.setAction("your_upload_servlet_url");
  RootPanel.get().add(form);

  // Add a file-upload to your form
  FileUpload fu =  new FileUpload();
  form.add(fu);

  // submit your form when the user selects a file
  fu.addChangeHandler(new ChangeHandler() {
    public void onChange(ChangeEvent event) {
      form.submit();
    }
  });
```

Comment: I have to go through so many setup steps & so many configuration, which make it more complicated. Do u know how to do with:
final FileUpload fileUpload = new FileUpload();

Comment: i got err:
The type org.apache.commons.fileupload.FileItem cannot be resolved. It is indirectly referenced from required .class files

Did i miss importing any package?

Comment: This is an error in your server side, right? are your trying to use gwtupload or is it your own servlet?. Anyway this is an typical error, you have to add to your project commons-fileupload.jar, and probably commons-io.jar and log4j.jar

Comment: Yes, it's server side erro:
"The import org.apache.commons.fileupload.FileItem cannot be resolved" 
How to get the FileItem class?

I included:
-commons-fileupload-1.2.1.jar
<br>
-commons-io-2.4.jar
-log4j-1.2.17.jar
-gwtupload-0.6.6.jar

But stil can't get rid of all errs

Comment: Definitively it is a classpath error, you have to be sure that those libraries are put in your WEB-INF/lib folder inside your .war file when packaging your app. If you use maven it is done automatic because gwtupload has those dependencies defined.

Comment: ok Thank you very much, I fixed the package, but now I got runtime Err when running in eclipse:
"log4j:WARN No appenders could be found for logger (org.apache.jasper.compiler.JspRuntimeContext).
log4j:WARN Please initialize the log4j system properly.
log4j:WARN See http://logging.apache.org/log4j/1.2/faq.html#noconfig for more info.
[WARN] 404 - POST /your_upload_servlet_url (127.0.0.1) 1409 bytes
   Request headers
      Host: 127.0.0.1:8888
      User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64; rv:20.0)

Comment: How can i test it in Eclipse?

Comment: The thing is i need to test it in Eclipse, cos inserting image code is depended on many other codes, so How can i see the File Uploading code work in eclipse?

Comment: You have to configure correctly your web.xml to handle the `your_upload_servlet_url` url. In the gwtupload [gettingStartedGuide](https://code.google.com/p/gwtupload/wiki/GwtUpload_GettingStarted)  you have an example of how to configure it for gwtupload, but for others servlets is equal. You have to be aware of the limited syntax of the `url-pattern` tag (`/path/*, /*, *.ext`)

Comment: What amazing, it's working in eclipse.

Thank you very very much for your help.!

Comment: 1 last question, after the image got showed on the page, where is the image file located?
I tried to run this line but nothing happened:
System.out.println(file.getAbsolutePath()+" file");

Comment: you said "
/// Create a temporary file placed in /tmp (only works in unix
// File file = File.createTempFile("upload-", ".bin", new File("/tmp"));" Right?

I am using Window 7, Then How to store the file into the desired location, say "C:\Temp"
I tried "File file = File.createTempFile("upload-", ".bin",new File("C:/Temp"));"
but it's not working